# Endless Http 404 error response loop in React.js app using Axios/Mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, mobx

I am working on a React.js app using Axios for HTTP processing and MobX for state management. I am getting this error, where I sent a test invalid HTTP response that should result in an 404 error. But what I got was a loop of 404 errors keep repeating itself, here's how the console looks:

[image: Endless error loop]

Here is the method that produces this error. I created a "debugging mode" version:

```
    // for testing
    @action loadActivityDos = async (id: string) => {
        let activity = this.getActivity(id);
        console.log("Step 1: get activity from local activityRegistry");
        if (activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            console.log("Step 2-1: set local activity to scoped activity");
        } else {
            this.loadingInitial = true;
            try {
                activity = await agent.Activities.details(id);
                runInAction('getting activity', () => {
                    this.activity = activity;
                    this.loadingInitial = false;
                })
                console.log("Step 2-2: get activity from API in the try block");
            } catch(error) {
                runInAction('get activity error', () => {
                    this.loadingInitial = false;
                })
                console.log("Errored -> error block");
            }
        }
```

First, the method hits the try block after failing to get the 'activity' from local array. The first line which awaits for the 'activity' from API throws an Http 404 error, sending to the catch block where the "Errored -> error block" logs in console.

It should end there, but after the "Errored -> error block" log, for an unknown reason it prints the "Step 1: get activity from local activityRegistry", meaning the whole method is ran from beginning again. Then it continues to repeat itself.

Here is the Axios code that communicates with the API, but I couldn't find anything that would cause this behavior:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://localhost:5001/api';

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;

const sleep = (ms: number) => (response: AxiosResponse) => 
    new Promise<AxiosResponse>(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(response), ms));

const requests = {
    get: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody),
}

const Activities = {
    list: ():Promise<IActivity[]> => requests.get('/activities'),
    details: (id: string) => requests.get(`/activities/${id}`),
}
```

I am oblivious why this loop is happening, if anyone could shed some light, I would be very grateful. I'll be happy to provide any other detail.

Answer (score 0):

From where `loadActivityDos` is called? Do you have a `reaction` to call it or maybe you use `useEffect`?

Maybe you have endless `reaction` loop which reacts to some flag you change

Or maybe `useEffect` does not have `deps` array in the end and is called every render.